# Debugging ASP.NET MVC in VS2013 shows source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

I have a project that worked find in VS2012 but since upgrading to VS2013 when I try and debug or Run it the source code for the page is displayed rather than the web page in the browser. This only happens in Chrome or Firefox, IE is fine.

[image: Source Showing]

Any ideas?

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS Express

Comment: Found I could fix the problem by disabling Browser Link, but still no idea of the reason.